# How do you access ViewState collection from PreviousPage on cross-page postback?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.net 2.0, the PreviousPage property of a web page does not have a ViewState collection. I want to use this collection to transfer information between pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View State is exclusive to the page.

If you want to transfer items,

- you can persist the data in a database, file, forms auth ticket or other cookie (Dont use Session or HttpContext.Current.Cache if you can help it)
- do a cross page post - from your first page, post back to the second page (and get the details from HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[] collection)
- put the values in a query string

Comment: I ended up using a cross page post, but accessing a public property on the first page (see below).

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpContext.Current.Items instead...ViewState is only good for the page it is on.

Comment: This method is simple and clean. I like it.

Comment: I tried to use this method, but I am posting directly from a link on the first page.  No code is executing where I can populate the HttpContext.Current.Items colection:

    <asp:linkbutton runat="server" id="Upload" text="Upload" postbackurl="~/uploadfeescheduleterms.aspx" />

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using PreviousPageType directive, by using some base page class that can hold your object.
For example you have class

```
public class BaseCrossPage:System.Web.UI.Page
{
     public List<Guid> Invitees = new List<Guid>();

}
```

So if first page derive from this class

```
public partial class Default : BaseCrossPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       this.Invitees = LoadInvitees();
    }


}
```

Then the page that you have posted to can access that object, assuming that previous page derived from  BaseCrossPage...

```
public partial class secondPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BaseCrossPage p = (BaseCrossPage)PreviousPage;
        List<Guid> Invitees = p.InvitedTeams
    }
}
```

kind of "viewstate" between pages...

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly. (See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(vs.80).aspx

Here's what you can do -

Create public properties on the first page exposing the information you want to share.  On the second page, set the PreviousPageType to the first page in the header of aspx file:

```
<%@ previouspagetype virtualpath="~/firstpage.aspx" %>
```

Then, get the values of these properties in the Load event of the second page:

```
If (Not MyBase.IsPostBack) Then

    _someValue = Me.PreviousPage.SomeValue

End If
```

Comment: Use the @ PreviousPageType directive to get strong typing against the PreviousPage property. "_someValue = firstPage.SomeValue" becomes "_someValue = Me.PreviousPage.SomeValue"